# is it possible to receive Dom in google webscript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scripting

I receive from google sheet some html tags to be displayed but it shows as raw string. here is how

Index.html

```
  <? var BlogData = getSheetData("Blogs"); ?>
  <? for(var i = 0; i < BlogData.length; i++) { ?>
        <div class="text-muted text-end"><?= BlogData[i][1] ?></div>
        <!-- BlogData[i][1] this should be dom but it displays as string -->
  <?};?>
```

code.gs

```
 function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
 }

 function getSheetData(sheetName)  { 
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById("1s5AHWsdfbsgfaegsdthwrthaert5ad4y4gt56355h");
    var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); 
    var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
    var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();  

   return dataValues;
  }
```

and the value comes from sheet `Blogs` look like this

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| `<h1>Title </h1>` |  |
| `<h2>Subtitle</h2>` |  |
| `<p>Paragraph</p>` |  |

and unfortunately it displays in the `Index.html` as string

*I need to show it as DOM not as string*

Comment: Then you will need to use a javascript snippet and a browser.  Or possibly the xmlService

Comment: @Cooper how to use xmlService ?

Comment: Thats a very broad question.  I guess I'd say to start by reading the documentation and doing some tutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally, I found the solution.

using google interpolation tags is a bit tricky and I don't know types of these tags. but accidently I found that solution.

using `<?= blogData[i][j] ?>` will return html tags as it is.

however, `<?!= blogData[i][j] ?>` will return html format.

using exclamation mark completely changes the result.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave this as an example of what [devoloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18673993/devoloper) was doing:

He created a deployment so you can retrieve `HTML` tags from a Spreadsheet, like this:

[image]

Now the problem was that the deployment was showing results as raw texts as:

[image]

By using the [HTML SCriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates) that App Script provides you can return the  data from the spreadsheet by passing the values through a script. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="root">
    <? const blogData = getSheetData("Blogs");?>
    <div>
      <? for(var i = 0; i < blogData.length; i++) { ?>
      <div>
        <? for (var j = 0; j < blogData[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <div>
          <?!= blogData[i][j] ?> // This is the solution that devoloper found
        </div>
        <?};?>
      </div>
      <?};?>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile("index")
    .evaluate()
}


function getSheetData(sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Blogs');
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange()
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  console.log(dataValues)

  return dataValues;
}
```

Once the above script is run the `HTML tags` added on the spreadsheet will return as a regular `HTML` DOM:

[image]